# Ubuntu 22.04.1 - this device is using manually-installed driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

i installed ubuntu desktop 22.04.1 and after opening additional drivers, i got message that says: no prooprietary drivers are in use, all options are grayed except continue using a manuially installed driver. I'm using lenovo g580 with intel hd4000 and external Nvidia 635m gpu. How could i resolve this and use nvidia proprietary driver?

Comment: Yeah i forgot to add question, i'm new here sorry, i edited post.

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal and type;

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

this should list some valid drivers and one of them should be marked as 'recommended'.

`sudo apt install <driver-from-list>`

Good luck